# prove that $\mu$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $X$ is a set, $S $ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and $w: X \to [0,\infty] $ is a function.
Define a measure $\mathcal{M} $ on $(X, S) $ by
$$\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} \omega(x) $$
for all $E\in S$

[Here the sum is defined as the supremum of all finite subsums
$\sum_{x\in D} \omega(x)$ as $D$ ranges over all finite subsets of $E$.]

Prove that $\mu(E)$ is a measure.
This an example, in the book Measure, integration & Real analysis, By Axler.
How do I prove that it is countably additive?

The idea I have to show that it is a measure is the following:

$\mu(\emptyset)=\sum_{x\in\emptyset}\omega(x)=0$, by vacuity (I don't sure).
Now, let $\{E_n\} $ be disjoint sets and $E=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n$

Let's proceed by cases:

1. suppose that $\mu(E)=\infty$. Fix $M>0$, let $A\subset E$ finite such that $M<\sum_{x\in A}\omega(x)$.
   Let $A_n=\{x\in A:x\in E_n\}$  Since all but finitely may $A_n$ are
   empty.
   $$M<\sum_{x\in E}\omega(x):=\sup\{\sum_{x\in A_n}: A_n\subset E_n\}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$$
   As $M$ is arbitrary, it's follow that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)=\infty$
   Therefore, $\mu(E)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)=\infty$

I hope you can understand me and give me some hint or help.
Thank you very much math friends.
2) $0<\mu(E)<\infty$ but here I don't know what to do...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: OK, thanks so much!

Comment: Note $A_n = \{x \in A : x \in E_n\}$ is more concisely written $A_n = A \cap E_n$.